# Lightswitch not working in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

I'm having trouble getting lightswitch to work on my home computer.

If I try to create a new lightswitch silverlight project I get the following message:

[image: alert]

If I try to open a project created on my laptop I see:

[image]

I've tried both to repair and reinstall visual studio with no change.

Any clues?

Comment: What [version](http://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-with-msdn-overview-vs) of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: It should work as stated here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/hh266747(v=vs.120).aspx Did you installed SQL Server Data Tools along with VS 2013?

Answer (score 3):

Have you installed it as an optional feature?

See this link:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/577ddba0-1440-43aa-8bba-18c587ee611f/open-project-lsproj-with-visual-studio-2013?forum=lightswitch

Specifically the install picture a few posts down:

[image: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/377799]

EDIT: You may have to select "Modify" (depending on installer) to see that screen.

Answer (score 1):

Which update of Visual Studio 2013 you have? As described [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/06e1a291-1a55-407d-b296-24faf04af4fa/due-to-a-known-issue-if-youre-developing-lightswitch-applications-we-recommend-not-installing?forum=lightswitch) Update 2 CTP 1 has known issues and not recommended to install for LightSwitch development.

Answer (score 1):

From Add/Remove Programs in the control panel, uninstall "SQL Server Data Tools 2013". Then re-install [VS 2013 Update 1](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2911573).

If the solution works, then you can try to reinstall SSDT by using the [standalone installer](http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/A/4/2A4211D0-AA9B-4496-A9D4-48CDBED5C25C/EN/SSDTSetup.exe).